pybind11 and poetry results in segmentation fault at execution
I am trying to bind a C++ library (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hansuelijud/arc-solution-source-files-by-icecuber/data) for Python with pybind11 and poetry.
I first started to only bind with pybind11 without poetry. It works.
I am now trying to add poetry but without success.
I made a first step by replacing the build process using make with cmake.
It resulted in two CMakeLists.txt, one for the library itself (icecuber) and one for the wrapper.
icecuber:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(icecuber)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS "src/*.hpp")

add_library(icecuber SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
target_include_directories(icecuber PUBLIC "include")

icecuber_wrapper:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(icecuber_wrapper)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "if/*.cpp")

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(icecuber_wrapper SHARED ${SOURCES} )

add_subdirectory(icecuber_lib)
target_link_libraries(icecuber_wrapper PRIVATE icecuber)

It may or not be the best solution (and here is not the question), but pybind11 is a submodule.
The result of the build is a icecuber_wrapper.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.
=> It works and I can run my Python code which imports icecuber_wrapper and calls the necessary bound functions.
myscript.py:
sys.path.insert(1, "build")
import icecuber_wrapper

[...]


Now I'm trying to use poetry to have a better packaging that I could ship to other people.
Thus, I modified my current setup with:
pyproject.toml:
[tool.poetry]
name = "icecuber"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "A wrapper for icecuber"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
safe_run = "icecuber.myscript:main"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
pybind11 = "^2.13.0"
psutil = "^6.0.0"

[tool.poetry.build]
script = "build.py"
generate-setup-file = true

[build-system]
requires = ["pybind11", "setuptools", "poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

build.py:
import pathlib

import pybind11
import pybind11.setup_helpers

pybind11.setup_helpers.ParallelCompile(
    "NPY_NUM_BUILD_JOBS",
    needs_recompile=pybind11.setup_helpers.naive_recompile,
).install()

ext_modules = [
    pybind11.setup_helpers.Pybind11Extension(
        "icecuber_wrapper",
        [
            str(fname)
            for fname in sorted(pathlib.Path("icecuber/icecuber_lib/src").glob("*.cpp"))
        ]
        + [str(fname) for fname in sorted(pathlib.Path("icecuber/if").glob("*.cpp"))],
        include_dirs=["icecuber/icecuber_lib/include/"],
        language="c++",
        cxx_std=17,
    ),
]


def build(setup_kwargs):
    setup_kwargs.update(
        {
            "ext_modules": ext_modules,
            "cmd_class": {"build_ext": pybind11.setup_helpers.build_ext},
            "zip_safe": False,
        }
    )

I removed the submodule for pybind11 as it is now included as Python package in poetry.
The build executes correctly as well as the install.
$ poetry build
$ poetry install

However, when I run my script myscript I get a segmentation fault.
$ poetry run myscript 

[1]    1588632 segmentation fault (core dumped)  poetry run myscript

The code of the library has not changed.
My script has changed only to remove adding the path when the .so is located (sys.path.insert(1, "build")).
I surely forgot to add a configuration somewhere, but I have no idea where.
Any suggestion ?
